# Assuming that we have a Binomial random variable X~Bin(n, 0.8), what is the smallest sample size n such that P(|(X/n)-0.8|>0.1)<0.01?

Tags: probability

Am I on the right track here?

To solve this question we can apply the central limit theorem. This states that with a sufficiently large sample size, the distribution of the sample mean will tend towards an approximately normal distribution.

We are given a binomial distribution of $X\sim Bin(n,0.8$)

The mean of a binomial distribution is given by $\mu = np$ where $n$ is the number of trials or sample size and $p$ is the probability of success.

In our question $\mu = 0.8\cdot n$.

The standard deviation of the binomial distribution is given by $\sigma = \sqrt{n\cdot p (1-p)}$.

In our question $\sigma = \sqrt{n\cdot 0.8 (1-0.8)}$.

This can be simplified to $\sigma = \sqrt{n\cdot 0.16}$

Our given problem can be rewritten as below:

$P\left(\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| >0.1\right) < 0.01$

$P\left(\left|\frac{X}{n}\right| >0.1+0.8\right) < 0.01$

$P\left(\left|\frac{X}{n}\right| >0.9\right) < 0.01$

$P\left(\left|X\right| >0.9n\right) < 0.01$

The random variable $X$ can now be standardized.

We know that for a large $n$ and following the central limit theorem that this variable can be approximated to $Z$ the standard normal variable with the following formula.

$Z = \frac{X-np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}}$ or $Z = \frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}$

$P\left(\left|\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}\right| >\frac{0.9n-\mu}{\sigma}\right) < 0.01$

We can now substitute in the previous values of $\mu = 0.8n$ and $\sigma=\sqrt{0.16n}$.

$P\left(Z >\frac{0.9n-0.8n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}\right) < 0.01$

This can be simplified to:

$P\left(Z >\frac{0.1n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}\right) < 0.01$

Let $k=\frac{0.1n}{\sqrt{0.16n}}$

Comment: Do you think your answer makes sense?

Answer (score 1):

Your statement
$$\Pr\left[\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| > 0.1 \right] = \Pr\left[\left|\frac{X}{n}\right| > 0.1 + 0.8\right]$$
is incorrect.

You can see this by choosing $X/n = 0$, which satisfies $|X/n - 0.8| > 0.1$, but not $|X/n| > 0.1 + 0.8$.  You can't just take a number out of an absolute value like that.

The correct approach is to write

$$\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| > 0.1 \iff \frac{X}{n} - 0.8 > 0.1 \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{X}{n} - 0.8 < -0.1.$$.

To make things a little easier, we will instead write

$$\Pr\left[\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| > 0.1\right] < 0.01 \iff \Pr\left[\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| < 0.1\right] > 0.99.$$
Then this lets us write
$$\Pr\left[\left|\frac{X}{n} - 0.8\right| < 0.1\right] = \Pr\left[0.7 < \frac{X}{n} < 0.9\right] = \Pr[0.7n < X < 0.9n].$$

Now we can standardize:
$$\begin{align}
\Pr[0.7n < X < 0.9n] &= \Pr\left[\frac{0.7n - 0.8n}{0.4\sqrt{n}} < \frac{X - np}{\sqrt{np(1-p)}} < \frac{0.9n - 0.8n}{0.4\sqrt{n}}\right] \\
&\approx \Pr\left[-\frac{\sqrt{n}}{4} < Z < \frac{\sqrt{n}}{4} \right] \\
&= 1 - 2 \Phi(\sqrt{n}/4)
\end{align}$$
where $\Phi$ is the cumulative distribution of the standard normal.  Hence we require
$$1 - 2 \Phi(-\sqrt{n}/4) > 0.99,$$
or equivalently,
$$n \ge 16 \left(-\Phi^{-1}(0.005)\right)^2 \approx 106.158.$$

So according to the normal approximation to the binomial, $n = 107$ would suffice.  However, we need to actually check that this is the minimum value, since we used an approximation to calculate it.

The exact probability is

$$\Pr[0.7n < X < 0.9n] = \sum_{x = \lfloor 0.7n \rfloor + 1}^{\lceil 0.9n \rceil - 1} \binom{n}{x} (0.8)^x (1 - 0.8)^{n-x}.$$  Checking $n = 107$, we get the exact probability

$$\Pr[74.9 < X < 96.3] = 0.99250568192042042684\ldots > 0.99.$$

Then the choice $n = 106$ gives

$$\Pr[74.2 < X < 95.4] = 0.98913140436303924794\ldots < 0.99.$$

So $n = 107$ is the desired minimum sample size.